# "error": "Parameter \"filter\" to findOneAndUpdate() must be an object, got \"5d713a66ec8f2b88b8f830b8\" (type string)"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing an API about Bootcamps. I am using nodejs and mongodb.

In my bootcamp controller i want to validate the ownership of the Bootcamp, meaning by this to check if the user trying to validate a certain bootcamp is actually the one that created the bootcamp or not.

The following is my update method:

```js
exports.updateBootcamp = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        let bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);
      
        if (!bootcamp) {
          return next(
            new ErrorResponse(`Bootcamp not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
          );
        }
      
        // Make sure user is bootcamp owner
        if (bootcamp.user.toString() !== req.user.id && req.user.role !== 'admin') {
          return next(
            new ErrorResponse(
              `User ${req.params.id} is not authorized to update this bootcamp`,
              401
            )
          );
        }
      
        bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true
        });
      
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: bootcamp });
      });
```

So i am getting a string which i think is correct but the error expects an object for some reason.

This is my model Bootcamp. So that you can see at the very end the relationship Bootcamp/User.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const geocoder = require('../utils/geocoder');

const BootcampSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength: [50, 'Name cannot be more than 50 characters']
    },
    slug: String,
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a description'],
        maxLength: [500, 'Description cannot be more than 500 characters']
        
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/,
            'Please use a valid URL with HTTP or HTTPS'
        ]
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: [20, 'Phone number cannot be longer than 20 characters']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
            'Please add a valid email'
        ]
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an address']
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            //GeoJSON Point
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point']
        },
        coordinates: {
            type:  [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
        },
        formattedAddress: String,
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: String,
        country: String
    },
    careers: {
        //Array of strings
        type: [String],
        required: true,
        enum: [
            'Web Development',
            'Mobile Development',
            'UI/UX',
            'Data Science',
            'Business',
            'Other'
        ]
    },
    averageRating: {
        type: Number,
        min: [1, 'Rating must be at least 1'],
        max: [10, 'Rating must can not be more than 10']
    },
    averageCost: Number,
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'no-photo.jpg'
    },
    housing: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobAssistance: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobGuarantee: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    acceptGi: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
      }
}, {
    toJSON: {virtuals: true}, 
    toObject: {virtuals: true}
});
```

Why is this happening? Is this has something to do with my model or my controller?

Comment: As far as I know, `findById` converts the argument into an object representing a full query by adding the field name to it (eg `{ _id: req.params.id }`. `findOneAndUpdate` does not and needs to have the field name(s) specified as a full query when called by the client application, eg (perhaps) `{ user: req.params.id }`

Comment: @user20042973 not following your idea. `req.params.id` which i am storing in `bootcamp` contains the id of the bootcamps i am looking for as a string and `bootcamp.user` gives me the user id as a new ObjectId. And `req.user.id` is the id of the user but as a string.

And to the method findOneAndUpdate i am sending a string `req.params.id` to look and filter into `req.body`

Comment: If you use `Bootcamp.findOneAndUpdate({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, ...`, does it work?

Comment: you are passing just the id as the first argument. since you are using `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `findByIdAndUpdate` it doesn't know which field to look from. so you need to explicitly pass the field as well `Bootcamp.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},....)`. if `findByIdAndUpdate` then you should be able to `Bootcamp.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,....)`